# How to exclude a specific div from jquery .click event

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I want to exclude alert when i click on **foo** but its still alerting when i click on anywhere on body including foo.
*the below Jquery is not working as expected.*

```
$("body:not(.foo)").click(function(){   alert("clicked body");    });
```

```js
$("body:not(.foo)").click(function()
{
 alert("clicked body");
});
```

```css
body {  background: #e8e6e4;  padding: 20px;  font-family: Helvetica;border:2px solid;}
.foo{  color:#ffffff;  background:red;}
button {  background: #0084ff;  border: none;  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 14px;  font-size: 15px;  color: #fff;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
<div>
  <p>Hello World</p><button>Change color</button>
</div>
<br><br><br><br><br><br>
<div class="foo">FOOOO</div>
</body>
```

Comment: I want to exclude foo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just return false when clicking that `.foo` div. [see demo](https://codepen.io/csandreas1/pen/aGKOZW)

```
$('div.foo').on('click', function() {
  return false;
});
```

Comment: Still have the problem . :(

Comment: It will work for the current situation, But i have multiple Jquery situations, if i use this my other functions are not working. it will helpful if you can give me an option otherthan **event.stopPropagation**

Comment: This is helpful i got next move. thank you @csandreas1

Comment: @AshikKH if it helped, you should mark this answer as the solution :)

Comment: this is not the exact answer but i got some idea

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I'd do it:

```
$(document).on('click', function()
{
    if (!$(this).hasClass('foo')) {
        //do something
    } 
}) ;
```